# For any index return the minimum of the previous two index

Tags: python, pandas

```
population = pd.DataFrame({'village': pd.Series([15,4,1,2], index=['boys','girls','men','women']),
    'town': pd.Series([20,36,26,28], index=['boys','girls', 'men', 'women'])})
```

Output:

```
----  town    village
boys    20      15
girls   36      4
men     26      1
women   28      2
```

For any index in the dataframe above, I want that particular index value to be the minimum value between the previous two index values.

For example I expect the the value for men in town to be 20 since it is the smaller value between (36,20)

I tried implementing it using `df.shift(2).cummin(axis=0)` but that didn't work.

Expected_output:

```
----  town    village
boys    NaN     NaN
girls   NaN     NaN
men     20      4
women   26      1
```

Comment: Use `population.shift(1).rolling(2).min()`?

Comment: @Zero I think that constitutes an answer. I'd post if I was you :)

Comment: thanks @zero that answered it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said by @Zero, so you can mark this as answered, you can use:

```
population.shift(1).rolling(2).min()
```